# Merge & center for multiple boxes

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to merge & center every values in this photo so each spans 2 boxes horizontally. May I ask are there ways to perform this, instead of manually 'merge & center' each of the values?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**

Use the `Merge & Center` option for the cells in the first row. While the new merged cell is selected click on `Format Painter` from the Home tab. Then select all the cells you want to merge.

**Method 2**

Select all cells you want to merge and choose the option `Merge Across` (from the `Merge and center` dropdown). Then center the text for the merged cells.

[image: excel]

Comment: Thanks, I tried for the first row and applied format painter, with that enabled I highlighted all the remaining values. However, what it did is unmerge the first row. May I ask am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: @Question It shouldn't act like that. What you do sounds right. Another thing you can do is to select all cells and from the 'Merge and center' dropdown choose the `Merge across` option and then center the text.

Comment: After you merge the first row, please move the mouse to the lower right corner of the merged cell, and drop down after the cross symbol appears.